# unable to access mysql db using python (both running on different containers)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, docker

I am trying to connect to mysql db using a python program. When run locally it works.

But while dockerizing the application I created, one container is for the python code and the other for the mysql db, when ran i this manner it fails to connect.

Python_code:

```
db.bind(provider='mysql', user='docker_root', password='password', host='db', database=database, port = 3306)
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
  services:
    app:
      image: app:latest
      links:
        - db
      ports:
        - "8001:8081"
      environment:
        - DB_HOST= db

    db:
      image: mysql:5.7.26
      restart: always
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'my_db'
        MYSQL_USER: 'docker_root'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
        - ./DB_config/:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d
```

And the docker-compose up fails with the eroor:

> pony.orm.dbapiprovider.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to
>   MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

Where am I going wrong? Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to exit your application in case it cannot connect to MySQL and set the restart policy to always, because `depends_on` does not guarantee that MySQL will be totally up when `app` starts but it is good to have it there.

```
version: "3"
  services:
    app:
      image: app:latest
      restart: always
      links:
        - db
      ports:
        - "8001:8081"
      environment:
        - DB_HOST= db
      depends_on:
        - db

    db:
      image: mysql:5.7.26
      restart: always
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'my_db'
        MYSQL_USER: 'docker_root'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
        - ./DB_config/:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d
```

And your application code should be something like:

```
try:
    db.bind(provider='mysql', user='docker_root', password='password', host='db', database=database, port = 3306)
except:
    # write some logs
    exit(1)
```

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what happens when we use depends on?

Comment: `depends_on` does not wait --in your case-- for `db` to be ready, it only makes sure that service `db` is started before `app` but it does not guarantee that `db` will be ready. Check this https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/ and check the note that says: 
> "There are several things to be aware of when using depends_on"

Comment: An example would be that container for `db` starts, then `app` will start but `db` startup process might take some time e.g. 3 seconds, so `app` will try to connect to something that is still starting

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up app`, it will also start `db`, but that’s about all it does.  It will start starting `db` before it starts starting `app` but as others have noted the MySQL startup can take a while.

Answer (score 1):

Try using container port `3306` -

```
db.bind(provider='mysql', user='docker_root', password='password', host='db', database=database, port = 3306)
```

Also, add `depends_on` attribute, you can remove the `links` attribute -

```
 depends_on:
    - db
```

Comment: still the same error. I have edited the question - according to this answer,

Comment: Try adding `depends_on` as well & then run the compose again.

Comment: even that didn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use depends_on flag as mentioned in accepted answer. If it does not solve your problem them use this approach.

After starting the container, your server will try to connect to the database server. sometimes database server may take some time to boot up and in this window, if the server tries to connect to database server it will face problems.
Try adding logic to reconnect database server after few seconds if the connection fails.

```
try{
   connectToDatabase();
   }catch(error){
   waitForHalfMinute();
   connectToDatabase();
}
```

Comment: Is this the same logic we are using while doing `depends_on` in the compose file? @vivekyadv4?

Comment: depend_on works partially, once you docker instance of database started, server will start. it will not check whether the port is open or not i.e. database is actually up or not. If your database instance takes time to boot up only depend_on flag will not work

Comment: Do we have any way to handle this in the compose file?

Comment: Not sure about this but probably no, cause I faced this problem and digged a lot through docker documentation for it